# XPath, содержащий '\r\n' не дает результата

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Есть страница:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div>
          text1 
    </div>
    <span>
        text2
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

И есть необходимость достать элемент li по тексту (потому что именно текст важен и нужен)
Используя вот такой искпас:

> //*[contains(text(),'text1')]\ancestor::li

Я могу найти элемент и даже текст выдается как "text1\r\ntext2" 
НО при попытке использовать икспас таким образом:

> //*[contains(text(),'text1\r\ntext2')]\ancestor::li

Не получаю никакого результата и элемент не находится
Есть ли какие-либо предположения, почему в первом случае я нормально получаю текст из li результатом `element.Text="text1\r\ntext2";` ноооо `/*[contains(text(),'text1\r\ntext2')]\ancestor::li` не работает как нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае можно использовать множественные условия:

```
[contains(text(),'text1') and contains(text(),'text2')]
```

это решение не оптимально, и мне кажется, что реальная задача может решаться проще...

Comment: спасибо! помогло мне ещё решение //*[contains(normalized-space(text()='text1 text2'))]